# $(...).knob is not a function in adminlte

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, adminlte

My code is below:

```
var html="<div class='row'>";
         for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
            {
            html+="<div class='col-1'><input type='text' value='75' class='knob' id='dial-'+i data-min='-50' data-max='50'></div>";

             $(function() {
                 $("#dial-"+i).knob();
                }); 
            } 
        html+="</div>";
         $("#lobSLA").html(html);
```

I am getting the below error.

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).knob is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):650)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: is that jquery plugin loaded?

Comment: also you have a closure around `i` so that won't fully do what you want.

Comment: yes plugin is loaded-- I am using a dynamic id

Comment: i see that but you have to becareful of closures in your `for` loop. aparently the plugin isin't loaded. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not working tried this too... I hope this resolves your for loop
var html="<div class='row'>";
   for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
   {
   html+="<div class='col-1'><input type='text' value='75' class='dial' id='dial-'+i data-min='0' data-max='100'></div>";
    
   /*  $(function() {
     $("#dial-"+i).knob();
       }); */ 
   } 
   $(function() {
    $(".dial").knob();
      });
  html+="</div>";
   $("#lobSLA").html(html);

Comment: @DipanjanBhattacharya have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was happening due to incorrect js file loading order. i changed it and it worked